# Region Growing in DM

Tags: dm-script

does anyone know any faster way of performing region growing within DM?
I have images of particles similar to the test image in the below example,
each particle having smaller areas with lower intensities inside the particle.
I want to grow these lowest intensity areas to fulfill the boundaries of the whole particle. 
This script works using dilation and 
if one puts x = 1024 or 2048, it is already way too slow....

edit:

I know the seg image before hand. But I dont see how one achieves the end
results with a simple tert() command since different particles have different values. The subregions idea might work, this would require particle counting. There is a menu command "analyze particles" that could do this, but how could
this be done fast scriptwise?
Here is an actual example:

[image]
( [External Link for full res TIF (DropBox)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/06pl835pq4004bs/example.tif?dl=0) )

For example the biggest particle would have full of values 29, the smallest number within that particle.
I also edited the code to work with the front image.

```
// $BACKGROUND$

image front:=getfrontimage()
image newfront = front


number x,y,i,su,su1,val=14,ok=1,count = 0,min,max,z,j,mmax=0
getsize(front,x,y)


image seg := binaryimage("",x,y)
image new := binaryimage("",x,y)


image mp:= binaryimage("",x,y)


minmax(front,min,max)



    image front1 = front
    seg=tert(front1>0,1,0)

    for(i=1;i<=max;i++)
    {

    new=tert(front1==i,1,0)
    su = sum(new)
    result(" int "+i+" of "+max+"  \n")
        while(ok)
        {
        mp = MPdilate( new ,7)
        mp = mp*seg
        if(sum(mp)==su) ok=0
        su = sum(mp)
        count++
        new=mp
        }
    ok=1
    front1 =  tert(new>0,i,front1) 
    }   


showimage(front1)
```

Comment: Did I understand it correclty, that you essentially want to flood-fill from a seed as long as intensities are higher? I'm not sure I understand correctly what your algorithm wants to achieve (in the presence of noise) and what the "boundary-conditions" are. In your example image, as simple tert() tresholding would result in the endresult already... (You may want to add a real-image to your post for clarity, maybe.)

Comment: In any way, there will not be a "region grow" command in scripting, so this is more an algorithm question than a coding question. Still we can discuss about more efficient ways of doing things once it is clear what the task is.

Comment: What is not clear to me is: Do you know the exact (geometric) boundary (i.e. your "seg" images), or not? Because, obviously, the task is differnt if you "just" want to fill in the holes in the known "seg" image.

Comment: BTW, an obvious way of speeding up your own algorithm would be to find the "subregion" of your particle first, and then only use the iterative dilate on this subimage, not on the full.

Comment: Hi 'Don I', please, when you "answer" to comments on StackOverflow, make sure to write a comment which address the person you want to answer to (using @username to send an alert to people). Edits in the main post do not automatically "show up" on the main-list and are easily missed. I've only now seen your edit from Oct 28th. I'm out of time right now, but I'll come back to it when I get the time.

Answer (score 0):

This is propably not what you're looking for, but your "goal" is still not 100% clear to me. From your question so far, it seems you *only* want a binary image of your mask, which you would simply get by keeping all 0-value images as zero and setting all others to 1. Could be done with **tert** or just a double "not":

```
image src := GetFrontImage()

image binMask = !!src
binMask.SetName( "Binary" )
binMask.ShowImage()
```

However, I guess your real goal is to get these binary mask for each *individual* particle on its own, i.e. to get 10 binary masks showing only one particle when you have 10 differnt (spatially separated) particles. This is a somewhat different task.

Answer (score 0):

In your post, you seem to say that the "Particle Analysis" is propably already doing what you want, so one solution to your problem might be to actually *use* the Particle Analysis right away!

Unfortunately, this part of the software is currently not properly accessible by a scripting API. However, with a little bit of 'out-of-the-box' thinking and some hacking-skills, one can access the needed functionality by using the UI-related command `ChooseMenuItem()`

I'm posting a littel example below which I've just hacked together. It first tresholds a binary input image, then applies the default particle-analysis, then grabs the results image and utilizes the contained information to crop out particles.

Excuse the sloppy coding, but you can propably modify this script to your needs.

```
number GetMeasurementsColumnIndex( image input, string colLabel )
{
    // Basic checks... return <0 if fail.
    if ( !input.ImageIsValid() ) return -1
    if ( input.GetName() != "Measurements" ) return -2
    if ( 0 == input.ImageCountImageDisplays() ) return -3

    imageDisplay disp = input.ImageGetImageDisplay( 0 ) 
    number sx = input.ImageGetDimensionSize( 0 )
    for( number c = 0; c<sx; c++ )
        if ( colLabel == disp.SpreadsheetImageDisplayGetColumnLabel(c) ) 
            return c

    return -4 // not found
}


// Main Script (Test)
number bOnNewWorkSpace = 1

// Pre-#1: Ensure relevant information is computed by particle Anlaysis
// The info is stored in the tags, but it seems it is only read from there
// on start-up... (needs checking)
GetPersistentTagGroup().TagGroupSetTagAsBoolean( "Private:Particles:Configuration:Length", 0 ) 
GetPersistentTagGroup().TagGroupSetTagAsBoolean( "Private:Particles:Configuration:Width", 1 ) 
GetPersistentTagGroup().TagGroupSetTagAsBoolean( "Private:Particles:Configuration:CenterX", 1 ) 
GetPersistentTagGroup().TagGroupSetTagAsBoolean( "Private:Particles:Configuration:CenterY", 1 ) 

// #1 Act on binary image mask based on front-image (temp)
image source := GetFrontImage()
image binSrc = !!source


// #2 Potentially work on "clean" workspace
if ( bOnNewWorkSpace )
{
    number wsID_src = WorkSpaceGetActive()
    number wsID_results = WorkSpaceAdd( WorkSpaceGetIndex(wsID_src) + 1 )
    WorkSpaceSetActive( wsID_results )
}

// #3 Treshold the mask by script. (Requires display)
binSrc.ShowImage()
imageDisplay disp = binSrc.ImageGetImageDisplay( 0 )
disp.RasterImageDisplaySetThresholdOn( 1 ) 
disp.RasterImageDisplaySetThresholdLimits( 0.1, 1 ) 

// #4 Perform Particle analysis, grab results, close temp. source
ChooseMenuItem( "Analysis", "Particles", "Analyze Particles" )
binSrc.DeleteImage()
image particleList := GetFrontImage()

// #5 Perfrom checks on results before proceeding. 
// (Particle Analysis may be configured by script by modifying persistent tags. See pre-step #1)
number pxIndex = GetMeasurementsColumnIndex( particleList, "CenterX" )
number pyIndex = GetMeasurementsColumnIndex( particleList, "CenterY" )
number pRIndex = GetMeasurementsColumnIndex( particleList, "MaxRadii" ) 

if ( pxIndex < 0 ) Throw( "Need to setup Analysis to create 'CenterX' output." )
if ( pyIndex < 0 ) Throw( "Need to setup Analysis to create 'CenterY' output." )
if ( pRIndex < 0 ) Throw( "Need to setup Analysis to create 'MaxRadii' output." )

// #6 Use results. Example Create Individual crops from source
//  ( This may still include intruding pixels from neighboring particles )
number nParticles = particleList.ImageGetDimensionSize( 1 )
nParticles = 5 // for testing...
for( number p = 0; p<nParticles; p++ )
{
    number px = particleList.GetPixel( pxIndex, p )
    number py = particleList.GetPixel( pyIndex, p )
    number pR = particleList.GetPixel( pRIndex, p )
    number y0 = py - pr
    number x0 = px - pr

    image crop := source.Slice2( x0,y0,0, 0,pR*2,1, 1,pR*2,1).ImageClone()
    crop.ShowImage()    
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your time and comments! I will try these out and see what works for me and post the script here!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to get pixel coordinates for each particle. To store it, you create a taglist of taglists. Start with BeMyGuest's terse codes, you can do this:

```
image source := GetFrontImage()
image binSrc = !!source
taggroup tgPartcleList=newTagList()
taggroup tgParticleIndividual=newTagList()
number val, x, y
while (1) {
   val=binSrc.max(x, y)
   if (val==0) break
   else {
      tgParticleIndividual=dfs(binSrc, x, y)
   }
   tgPartcleList.taggroupInsertTagAsTagGroup(infinity(), tgParticleIndividual)
   turnOffpixels(binSrc, tgParticleIndividual)
}
```

the dfs function is "depth first search". Basically, it is one type of "linked components search". There are many algorithms for it. I used "depth first", which can be coded with stack structure simulated with taggroup. 
after each dfs, you call "turnOffpixels" function to darken that particle and back to the loop.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what your 'dfs()' would do. Return a tagList of connected pixels in binSrc? Could you post the 'dfs()' ?

Comment: Yes. return a taglist of connected pixels, starting point is (x,y). I cannot post the full code here because of workplace restriction. The algorithm can be found here: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/depth-first-traversal-for-a-graph/.

Comment: Thanks for the link. How fast is a DM-script based implementation of the algorithm approximately? I imagine that using single-pixel operation in a for-loop is pretty slow... But the algorithm will only encounter those "connected" pixels, not all of the pixels in the image?

Comment: total pixels = 11885 Duration:2.74526sec

Comment: total pixels = 24773 Duration:9.5487sec. Yes. Only connected pixels. The time quoted here is for a 1024 x 1024 image with many bright lines. The total time is for the total bright pixels, each linked cluster is grouped in individual taglist, and all clusters are grouped in one master taglist. It is not fast. Definitely much slower than the multi projection method by Schaffer, but that is for the all bright pixels in the binary image.

Comment: My understanding is that one cannot get away from pixel by pixel operation for counting connected points. Because you need to constantly checking neighbor relationship. Will be happy to see if there is a faster way.

Comment: total pixels, numberOfClusters = 24785, 568 Duration:8.75389sec. This is the real time for searching only. Previous was ran with extra actions of cleaning out clusters with size smaller than a threshold.